# How to configure two authentication providers for the same firewall?

Tags: symfony, authentication

I am using symfony2.7 and I would like to authenticate my users whether by form login or by token in the url request. I am able to do both separately but how could I configure my firewall to be able to listen for both authentication methods whether user logs in by form or by token.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a [Guard](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html). With a Guard it doesn't matter which authentication method you choose.